# Meteor: A issue rendering a data structure

Tags: meteor

The problem I have is that the data structure below is what I'm trying to render in my template.  It will only work if one array element is returned from the function that returns the data.

I have an array of arrays of objects, like so (only one object per array element):

```
[ [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [ 
   { 
     businessDetails: { companyName: 'Companyname' },
       address: 
        { firstName: 'firstname',
          lastName: 'last name',
          addressLineOne: 'address line one',
          addressLineTwo: 'address line two',
          city: 'city',
          postCode: 'postcode',
          email: 'email',
          phoneNumber: '123456879',
          mobileNumber: '123456789' 
        },
      paymentDetails: { paypalEmail: 'email' },
      createdBy: 'jERFPGRv6oPTFqjWb',
      _id: 'LrqDm5LJcBpo5wW7W' 
    } 
  ] 
 ]
```

This structure is created like so:

```
var businesses=[];
  for(var i=0; i<recs.length; i++){
     businesses[i] = BusinessDetails.find({createdBy: recs[i].BusinessDetailsId}).fetch();
  }
//this works and the data in this element is rendered as expected
return businesses[0];

//this doesn't render anything
return businesses;
```

This part of the template works if only one array element is passed to it.

```
{{#each businesses}}
   createdBy: {{createdBy}}
       {{#with businessDetails}}
           {{companyName}}
       {{/with}}
{{/each}}
```

Can anyone suggest how I should render the data structure above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array of arrays. If that's the data structure you intended, then you'll need an `each` within an `each` like this:

```
{{#each businesses}}
  {{#each this}}
    createdBy: {{createdBy}}
      {{#with businessDetails}}
        {{companyName}}
      {{/with}}
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed thank you :)  ... Not exactly sure if I'm going about getting the data in the best way possible but that did the trick!